# The User Profile Service failed the logon. User profile cannot be loaded

Tags: windows, windows-7, user-profile

I'm getting this error on a users desktop.

> The User Profile Service failed the logon.
>
> User profile cannot be loaded.

Unfortunately the local administrator account is disabled (we are at a large organization and can not use the domain admin account either).  We can not remote desktop into the machine but we are able to remotely administer the machine via other mechanisms and are able to access file shares.

Any ideas on how we might be able to resolve this problem?

Comment: What are your other options for remote administration?

Comment: All the normal ways you can remotely administer Windows based boxes (except remote desktop).  I don't have any third party administration software installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, while I was working on my question I found a solution that worked well for me.

- From a second machine launch `regedit` from the Run dialog
- Connect to the remote registry File > Connect Network Registry...
- Follow these [directions](http://www.vistax64.com/tutorials/130095-user-profile-service-failed-logon-user-profile-cannot-loaded.html)

Answer (score 0):

Also, something that occurred for us...we ran into registry size issues, which ultimately led to the same problem

Changing `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\RegistrySizeLimit` to be larger (for us, we used 8 f's...4GB worth of expansion room. This fixed a lot of issues for us.